# How to enable a button with useRef() in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I created a Todo-list app in react
and inside each item placed one radio button and one edit, delete button for each and every item when a user enters in the input text.
Basically, the edit, delete buttons are disabled at first.
when a user clicks on the radio button then the particular item buttons get enabled.
But here I am getting all the buttons in each item gets enabled inside the list

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import {AiFillDelete,AiFillEdit} from 'react-icons/ai';
import './App.css';
Modal.setAppElement('#root')
function App() {
  const [todos,setTodos] = useState([{id:0,text:"item1"},{id:1,text:"item2"}])
  const [todo,setTodo] = useState("")
  const [todoEditing,setTodoEditing] = useState(null)
  const [editingText,setEditingText] = useState("")
  const [deleteItem,setDeleteItem] = useState()
  const [editItem,setEditItem]=useState()
  const [modalIsOpen,setModalIsOpen] = useState()
  
  function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    const newTodo = {
      id:todos.length,
      text : todo,
    }
    setTodos([newTodo].concat(...todos))
    setTodo("")
  }

  function deleteTodo(id){
    const updateTodos = [...todos].filter((todo)=>todo.id !== id)
    setTodos(updateTodos)
  }

  function editTodo(id){
    const updateTodos = [...todos].map((todo) => {
      if(todo.id===id){
        todo.text = editingText
      }
      return todo
    })
    setTodos(updateTodos)
    setTodoEditing(null)
    setEditingText("")
  }

  const handleRadioBtnItem = (event) =>{
    setDeleteItem(event.target.value);
    setEditItem(event.target.value);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='todo-head'>
      <h1 className='ForHeading'>Todo List</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <input className='User-Input' type='text' onChange={(e)=>setTodo(e.target.value)} value={todo}/>
       <button className='Add-Btn' type='submit' disabled={!todo}>Add Todo</button>
      </form>
      </div>
       {todos.map((todo)=>
         <ul className='ul-Style' key={todo.id} id={todo.id}>
         <input className='Rdo' type='radio' onClick={handleRadioBtnItem}/>
         {todoEditing === todo.id ? 
          (
            <div>
            <Modal 
              isOpen={modalIsOpen} 
              shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false} 
              style={
                {
                  overlay:{
                    backgroundColor:'gray'
                  },
                  content:{
                    textAlign:'center'
                  }
                }
              }
            >
            <h2>Edit Items</h2>
            <input type='text' onChange={(e)=> setEditingText(e.target.value)} value={editingText}/>
            <div>
              <button onClick={()=>editTodo(todo.id)} disabled=''>Save</button>
              <button onClick={()=>setModalIsOpen(false)}>Close</button>
            </div>
            </Modal>
            {todo.text}
            </div>
          )
          :
          (
              <p>{todo.text}</p>
          )
         }
         <button 
          className='Edit-Btn' 
          onClick={()=>{setTodoEditing(todo.id);setModalIsOpen(true)}} 
          disabled={!editItem}><AiFillEdit/>
         </button>
         <button 
          className='Del-Btn' 
          onClick={()=>deleteTodo(todo.id)} 
          disabled={!deleteItem}><AiFillDelete/>
         </button>
       </ul>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Check this, if it can help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613037/disable-button-based-on-unique-key-in-react

Comment: you can implement it in your functional, just implement it accordingly. The logic seems to be identical, no?